# Lattice dotplot not showing count for y-values in R

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

I'm very inexperienced with R, but I'm required to use it for the statistics class I'm taking. I'm trying to make a dot plot using

```
library(lattice)
dotplot(Bio$SS,
main = "Plants by Number of Short Shoots",
xlab = "Number of Short Shoots",
ylab = "Number of Plants",)
```

However, the graph doesn't provide a count for the y-value. It looks like this instead:
[image: It looks like this instead:]
As you can see, there are no y-values given to the dot plot, even though it should be listing the number of plants with each value. When I made a histogram using a similar formula it worked fine:

```
hist(Bio$SS,
    main = "Plants by Number of Short Shoots",
    xlab = "Number of Short Shoots",
    ylab = "Number of Plants",
    col = "green")
```

Here is how that turned out:
[image: Here is how that turned out:]
This one properly provided the count for a y-value. How can I make the dotplot do the same?

Here's the data I'm using:

```
structure(list(ï..Block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("NFCT", "NFNP", "SFCT", "SFNP"), class = "factor"), 
    Plant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Stem = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), SS = c(4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L), LS = c(4L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L), Leaves = c(30L, 30L, 13L, 32L, 32L, 35L, 33L, 
    34L, 27L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 29L, 
    20L, 20L, 22L, 25L, 23L, 13L), Inf. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TLength = c(10.5, 11.2, 6.2, 12.2, 11.3, 
    11.5, 11.9, 11.7, 10, 11.5, 10.9, 12.2, 12.6, 12.2, 12.1, 
    12, 6.5, 6.7, 13, 6.2, 7.6, 5.9, 7.7, 6, 5.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you include `dput(data)` in th equestion so we can help you?

Comment: Sorry, data is attached now. Hopefully that's what you meant. I'm not entirely familiar with dput(data).

Comment: Please don't attach data using links. Provide data using `dput(head(data,25))`

Comment: Sorry, hopefully this is right? First time posting here, so I'm not yet familiar with the standard procedure.

Comment: The code provided for your data doesn't seem right. Please check.

Comment: What isn't right about it? I seem to be able to load it into R fine.